# W3C Validation Warning, name attribute phasing out ? What would happen with PHP $_POST and forms submissions?

Tags: php, html, attributes, w3c, w3c-validation

Any idea's what would be the successor of the name attribute ?

As per the w3c validator ....

```
Validation Output: 4 Warnings

Below is a list of the warning message(s) produced when checking your document.

    Warning Line 12, Column 21: The name attribute is obsolete. Consider putting an id attribute on the nearest container instead.

    <p><a name="_GoBack"></a></p>
```

Ok so we don't really care about the actual line of code ... what I care most about is the NAME attribute ... If they are deprecating it how would we submit out input fields to php ??

That is my main question ... Thanks

Comment: name attributes are still valid in form elements. It's just depracated in anchor elements.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This warning is talking specifically about `anchor` elements. The `name` attribute is still perfectly valid for form elements.

For `anchor`s it's been deprecated in favor of `id`, which you can use to link to via a hashtag.

Comment: ok :) I just got scared there for a moment ... Where do you keep up with all this info :)

Comment: The W3C site :) http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/#h-4.10 http://www.w3.org/TR/html5/obsolete.html#attr-a-name

Comment: it would be nice if the validator could point to the link just below the error ...